# How can I get commit value in controller when uploading file with Ajax. Rails 3.2

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

My Environment

- Rails 3.2.1
- ruby 1.9.3p194 (2012-04-20 revision 35410) [x86_64-darwin11.4.0]
- jquery-rails (2.0.2)
- paperclip (3.0.4)

I want to get value of "commit" in controller.

```
<%= form_for @foo, :url => '/foo/edit/',:remote => true, :html => {:multipart => true}, :id => "peroform" do |f| %>
  <%= f.file_field :logo %>
  <%= f.submit "logo" %>
<% end %>
```

When I don't choose any file, I can get the commit value.

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"****", "commit"=>"logo"}
```

However I choose a file, the value is removed in the Parameter.

```
  Parameters: 
    {"foo"=>{"logo"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007fd2c0277e88 @original_filename="bar.png", @content_type="image/png", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"foo[logo]\"; filename=\"bar.png\"\r\nContent-Type: image/png\r\n", @tempfile=#<File:/tmp/RackMultipart20120531-44915-r5kb52>>}, "utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"*", "remotipart_submitted"=>"true", "X-Requested-With"=>"IFrame", "X-Http-Accept"=>"text/javascript, application/javascript, application/ecmascript, application/x-ecmascript, */*; q=0.01"}
```

How can I get commit value?

Then I want to user multiple submit like this.
I want to save only 'logo' when the "logo submit" is pushed,
but I want to save 'name' and 'logo' when the "all submit" is pushed.

```
<%= form_for @foo, :url => '/foo/edit/',:remote => true, :html => {:multipart => true}, :id => "peroform" do |f| %>
  <%= f.file_field :logo %>
  <%= f.submit "logo" %>

  <%= f.text_field :name %>
  <%= f.submit "all" %>
<% end %>
```

Do you have any idea for this multiple submit button.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: are you using http://github.com/formasfunction/remotipart? without that remote file upload wont happen. as for multi submit, sure you want the user to have to think? why not just allow optional values with one button submit?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I don't use remotipart.I use [link](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip) for uploading image files. The form is long and divided by some parts. the submit buttons is into each parts and the all save button in the bottom of the form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hm...i think this is a bug, but u can bind eventhandlers to submit buttons, and insert additional param(commit name) before submit. Then in controller based on commit param decide what u want to save.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will try to upload file without jquery-rails.

Comment: try remotipart gem, maybe it helps

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I will try remotipart.